# Could not find or load main class when adding package statement

Tags: java

I have `/hel/javaCode/Min.java`:

```
package javaCode;

public class Min {
    ...
}
```

And `/hel/javaCode/project/Test.java`:

```
package javaCode.project; // When commented, I get the right output
import javaCode.*;

public class Test { 
    ...
}
```

`echo $CLASSPATH` is :

```
.:/home/hel
```

`javac Test.java` is correct. But when I run `java Test`, this error message appears:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Test

When I comment the line: `package javaCode.project;` int Test.java. No error message and the program is correct.

Comment: Just curious: Do you have to run this from the command line?

Comment: Why do you use `;` after the `class Min { ... }`?

Comment: What is class MyMain?

Comment: @Ksenia Sorry for editing.

Comment: Hard to see what you are expecting here. If `Test` is in package `javaCode.project`, the correct `java` invocation is `javaCode.project.Test`. See the documentation.

Comment: @EJP Yeah. But I thought maybe sth wrong with CLASSPATH or other things.

Comment: @EJP Indeed. I'm confused. In $CLASSPATH, there is `.`. It means current directory. So I think `java Test` may work.

Comment: But it doesn't, does it? And it's not what it says in the documentation either. So why on earth *would* you expect it to work? The documentation clearly states that you have to provide the complete class name including the package. So do that, and stop expecting the impossible.

Comment: @EJP Do you mean the doc of `man java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `java javaCode.project.Test` which is the FQN (Full Qualified Name) of your class indeed you need to add the package name to get the real class name.

Comment: Yeah. It works. Why `javac Test.java` works, but `java Test` fails? `java javaCode.project.Test` is right. Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: because as mentioned the name of the class is not Test but package name + Test. If you add a file /hel/Test.java, Test will be its name as there is no package name since your are in the root directory. The java program expects  the full qualified name of your class

Comment: In $CLASSPATH, does member `.` make `java Test` work in current direcotry?

Comment: Only if Test has no package name

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
java javaCode.project.Test
```